# Retrieving more than 30 messages using streams/symbols

Tags: stocktwits

#### Background

Given a symbol (i.e. cashtag), I need to retrieve twits from 2015 up to 2019 in order to perform sentiment analysis for a research project.

#### Problem

The public API is limited to the last 30 messages, as explained in https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-symbols-docs.

```
https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/NVDA.json
```

I tried the same request in an authenticated manner, but I face the same limitation.

```
https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/NVDA.json?access_token=<access_token>
```

#### Question

Is there a way to work around the limitation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. You should contact their support team, to get Partner level access to download historical data.

"There are some endpoints and data that are not available in the public Stocktwits API, including the full firehose data stream of our content. You may also have an application that requires higher usage limits (rate, message or other limits) than the public API. These additional capabilities are highlighted in the API documentation. If your application requires access to these capabilities, please  contact our team to discuss."

https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/contact